# Getting the class of the predictors from an lme4 model

Tags: r, dataframe, class, lm, lme4

After fitting an `lme4` model, I was wondering how we get the class of the predictors from `terms(fit)[[3]]`?

Here is a simple example, but I appreciate a functional answer for any other model in `lme4`.

**Note:** Everything has to be extracted from the model.

```
library(lme4)

h <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hkil/m/master/h.csv')
h$year <- as.factor(h$year)
m <- lmer(scale~ year*group + (1|stid), data = h)

terms(m)[[3]]  ## What are the `class`es of the variables in here (e.g., `integer`, `factor` etc.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not perfectly robust, but:

1. extract the names of variables from the terms object

```
av <- all.vars(terms(m)[[3]])   ## c("year","group")
```

2. Look them up in the data frame supplied as `data=`:

```
setNames(lapply(av, function(x) class(h[[x]])), av)
$year
[1] "factor"

$group
[1] "character"
```

If you want to get everything from the model this gets **MUCH HARDER** in general, because the original variables are not necessarily stored.  In the example you gave this works:

```
 setNames(lapply(av, function(x) class(model.frame(m)[[x]])), av)
$year
[1] "factor"

$group
[1] "factor"
```

You'll notice that `group` has been converted to a factor.  You can break this, e.g., by using a term like `log(x)` in the model ...

Comment: OK.  Be aware that this recipe will definitely break sometimes (e.g. my `log(x)` example): this has been a long-standing pain point for me in developing machinery based on R models.  If the model frame doesn't work you can try to fall back on eval(getCall(m)$data), but that relies on being in an environment where the original data object can still be found ... if all else fails you can insist that the user provide the `data` object separately to your post-hoc function.

Comment: If you just want columns that exist in the model matrix you can look at `getME(m,"X")`.  But if you have transformations in the formula you may need to work a bit harder to match up elements in the terms with columns of the model matrix ...